# Basic C cast warning pointer from int

Tags: c, casting, comparison, compiler-warnings, char-pointer

Can someone tell me how to correct this warning/error. I am trying to get just the first character of a string to tell if it a "-".

Error:

```
grep-lite.c:15:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   if(strcmp((char *) pattern[0],"-") == 0)
             ^
grep-lite.c:29:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   while(strcmp((char *) argv[index][0],"-"))
                ^
```

Source with warnings/errors:

Line 15:

```c
if (strcmp((char *) pattern[0],"-") == 0)
```

Line 29:

```c
while (strcmp((char *) argv[index][0],"-"))
```

Complete Source:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "grep-lite.h"

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
  //initailize variables
  int index = 1, lineNumber = 1;
  int oneMatchingLine = FALSE;
  int invertOpt = FALSE, lineNumOpt = FALSE, quietOpt = FALSE;
  char * pattern = argv[argc];

  //check if last arguement is invalid by starting with a '-'
  if(strcmp((char *) pattern[0],"-") == 0)
    {
      error(INVALID_PATTERN);
      return EXIT_ERROR;
    }

  //check if they asked for help
  if(strcmp(argv[index],"--help") == 0)
    {
      printHelpStatement();
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    //walk through all options
  while(strcmp((char *) argv[index][0],"-"))
    {
      //find and set option
      if(processOptions(argv[index], &invertOpt, &lineNumOpt, &quietOpt))
    index++;
      //if invalid option fai
      else
    {
      error(INVALID_OPTION);
      return EXIT_ERROR;
    }
    }

  //walk through stdinput searching for pattern relationship
  while(feof(stdin) == 0)
    {
      //initialize
      char * thisLine = NULL;

      // get read line with fgets
      thisLine = fgets(thisLine, MAX_CHARACTERS, stdin);

      //find pattern location in thisLine
      char * patternLoc = strstr(thisLine, pattern);

      //check if we should print this line based of patternLoc and invertOpt
      if((!patternLoc != NULL && !invertOpt) || (pattenLoc == NULL && invertOpt))
    {
      //see if we should print this line
      if(!quietOpt)
        printLine(thisLine, lineNumOpt, lineNumber);
    }
      lineNumber++;
    }
```

Comment: note that `argv[argc]` accesses `argv` out-of-bound (last element is at `argc-1`).

Comment: `if (pattern[0] == '-') { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will enumerate the problems I find in your code

1. The correct usage of `strcmp()` exists in your code, in this line

   ```
   if (strcmp(argv[index],"--help") == 0)
   ```

   `strcmp()` is intended for string comparison, not character comparison, this

   ```
   if(strcmp((char *) pattern[0],"-") == 0)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   if (pattern[0] == '-')
   ```

   do not cast the variable to force compilation, instead find the actual cause for the compiler error/warning.
2. You have a severe error, you don't allocate space for the `thisLine` `char` pointer, you must allocate memory via `malloc()` or just declare it as a `char` array like

   ```
   char thisLine[SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER];
   ```

   Also, this

   ```
   while(feof(stdin) == 0)
   ```

   is never a good [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/1983495) instead do it like this

   ```
   char thisLine[100];
   while (fgets(thisLine, sizeof(thisLine), stdin) != NULL)
   ```
3. You made another very common mistake, arrays in c are indexed from `0` to `N - 1`, so

   ```
   char *pattern = argv[argc]
   ```

   is wrong, because you are reading one element after the last, the correct code is

   ```
   char *pattern = argv[argc - 1]
   ```

   which will give you the last element.

Comment: @napkinsterror I expect your program to crash or something similar if you don't read the updated answer.

Comment: I understand those errors, was just mad I could not correct the basic pointer problem, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @napkinsterror don't forget to check `argc` to prevent reading beyond the bounds of `argv`...

Comment: Also, argv[argc] is beyond the end of the array.